# How to edit an array which stores time values in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I am storing time values in an array. The time is getting stored in the array through a key name called @"time" when a particular date is selected from datepicker. This date I am using to schedule notification for a particular date.

I am using sqlite database where I am saving my notification time values. My problem is I want to edit my already scheduled notification through the key value that I am used store in my array i.e if I change a particular time that particular time should get changed in my array of time through the index path at that index, where it should get edited?

Comment: question is a bit vague... can u make it more clear? And also do you work in kiwitech?

Answer (score 0):

fetch all scheduled notifications `array` via `scheduledLocalNotifications`

check for `fireDate` in a loop on `array` for which you want to reschedule (old date/time)

when you find the notification's object you want to reschedule, cancel that notification via `cancelLocalNotification`.
when old notification is cancelled, schedule a new local notification with your updated time.

Comment: as you told is perfectly correct,but i am confused at one point if i am having 20 notifications which i am displaying in my tableview and when i am clicking on any cell and changing its time that particular notification should get edited.So how could i get the index number of the notification array so that i can edit.

Comment: you can use a traditional C++ for loop (i=0;i<[array count];i++)
 and where your notification gets a match, you can see the value of "i" to get the index of notification.

Comment: i have tried this NSArray *eventArray = [application scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
    {
     UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
     
NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo;
NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"idtemp"]];
NSString *uidtodelete =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",am.AlarmID];
          if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
 {
  [application cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
     break;
  }
     
 }

Comment: NSArray *eventArray = [application scheduledLocalNotifications]; 
 NSString *uidtodelete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",am.AlarmID]; 

 for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++) 
 { 
  UILocalNotification *oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
  NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo; 
  NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"idtemp"]]; 
  if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete]) 
  { 
   [application cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent]; 
   break; 
  } 
 }